# Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'tblUsers' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Всем привет, не могу понять как задать поле у класса.
Использую node v10.11.0

Вот такой код:

Users.js

```
class Users {

        constructor(sequelize, Sequelize) {
            this.sequelize = sequelize;
            this.tblUsers = this.sequelize.define('users', {
                id: {
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                    primaryKey: true
                },
                login: Sequelize.STRING,
                pass: Sequelize.STRING
            });
        }

        checkAuthUser(req) {
            this.sequelize.sync().then(function () {
                this.tblUsers.findOne({ // вот эта 17 строка про которую говориться в ошибке
                    where: {
                        login: req.body.login,
                        pass: req.body.pass
                    }
                }).then(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.dataValues) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        }

    }

module.exports = Users;
```

И вот такой index.js

```
const user = require('./src/Users');
var Users = new user(sequelize, Sequelize);
    app.post('/auth/', function (req, res) {
        Users.checkAuthUser(req);
        res.send('asds');
    });
```

Но при отправке формы на /auth методом POST получаю ошибку:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'tblUsers' of undefined                                                                                             
    at /Users/qwerty/src/sport/src/Users.js:17:18
```

Я понимаю, что в ошибке говориться про, то что типа не задано поле tblUsers класса Users, но я не понимаю как его тогда правильно задать. Во всех документациях по ES6 и ES5 приводится пример, где таким образом как у меня в конструкторе создаются(инициализируются) поля класса.

```
this.tblUser = 'какие-то данные';
```

Помогите плиз я очень чета туплю :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
checkAuthUser(req) {
  var tblUsers = this.tblUsers;
  this.sequelize.sync().then(function () {
      tblUsers.findOne({ // вот эта 17 строка про которую говориться в ошибке
          where: {
              login: req.body.login,
              pass: req.body.pass
          }
      }).then(function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          if (data.dataValues) {
              return true;
          } else {
              return false;
          }
      });
  });
}
```

я думаю, что ошибка из-за видимости переменных

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ваш ответ в некоторой степени помог мне, я скопировал написанный вами метод попробовал запустить и получил ошибку "tblUsers.findOne is not a function"

После чего я понял что ошибка в том, что js асинхронный и tblUsers не успевает инициализироваться. Погуглив еще я нашел вопрос с точно такой же проблемой и там было, то что мне надо ))

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903574/nodejs-promise-typeerror-cannot-read-property-then-of-undefined

Comment: Ну хотя бы так помог)

Comment: Ай короч я совсем тупой, ошибка "tblUsers.findOne is not a function" была потому что я там натворил всякой фигни пока ждал ответа. Ваш ответ действительно помог, все дело в области видимости